# stream divx/mkv to html5 video with ffmeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm looking into making something that can play divx/mkv videos with html 5 video.
I don't know much about ffmpeg or streaming so this may be a simple question.
With ffmpeg I could transcode the video to a mp4 file and then stream it with the html 5 video tag.
But is there a way to do the streaming without writing it to disk first?
If it is possible, can someone point me in the right direction?
I'm planning on writing this in Go, but the language is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the filename `-` in FFmpeg to signify STDOUT, and pipe this data directly to the client.  Beware though that this means you cannot use seeking in the stream, and that many codecs and containers won't work properly.

Comment: Some codecs need to go back to the beginning of the file after writing to write pointer data and what not. This is impossible if the data had already been sent.